# JavaScript throws the following error: SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement

Tags: javascript

The following code block throws the error in Mozilla Firefox: SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement. Can anyone tell me where this } is missing and what I am doing wrong here?

Edit: You can inspect element at https://burrim.github.io/recordsblog/ to see that error. The Script is the fourth, located in the head.

Many Thanks!

```
function OpenCloseNav() {
"use strict";
var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 50em)");
var x = document.getElementById("_sidebar");
var y = document.getElementById("_main");
var z = document.getElementById("_menu");
if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at least 50em
        if (x.style.width === "0rem") {
        y.style.marginLeft = "22rem";
        y.style.marginRight = "4rem";
        x.style.width = "18rem";
        x.style.marginLeft = "0rem";
        z.style.left = "16rem";
    } else {
        y.style.marginLeft = "10.5rem";
        y.style.marginRight = "9.5rem";
        x.style.width = "0rem";
        z.style.left = "0.25rem";
   }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Try putting a semicolon after your last accolade: "};"

Comment: No it does not: https://jsfiddle.net/apkpxx9g/

Comment: also the semicolon does not help. thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

The following code worked, no idea why the above was not..

```
function OpenCloseNav() {
"use strict";
var x = document.getElementById("_sidebar");
var y = document.getElementById("_main");
var z = document.getElementById("_menu");
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 50em)").matches) {
    if (x.style.width === "0rem") {
        y.style.marginLeft = "22rem";
        y.style.marginRight = "4rem";
        x.style.width = "18rem";
        x.style.marginLeft = "0rem";
        z.style.left = "16rem";
    } else {
        y.style.marginLeft = "10.5rem";
        y.style.marginRight = "9.5rem";
        x.style.width = "0rem";
        z.style.left = "0.25rem";
   }
  }
}
```